# Four hosts showing up on netdiscover without any computers connected

Tags: networking

When I ran netdiscover, I found a couple hosts that I'm not familiar with. Two of them have almost the same MAC address as my router, but have IPs starting with 100. / 10. .

When I searched about the IPs it redirected me to IANA whois, and on their site it say the IPs are Shared Address Spaces. 
Why are these addresses showing up on my network ?

> **2c:e4:12:ee:86:c4** 
>      ,  **2c:e4:12:ee:86:c2**
>     , **2c:e4:12:ee:86:c5**

Answer (score 0):

These would be additional Physical Interfaces that your computer is also connected to - the Router will have a unique MAC address for each interface (WIFI, LAN, WAN) so check the config page for it and I'm sure you'll find these MAC addresses there.